# how to order the boxes in side by side box plots?

Tags: r, boxplot

I am trying to create a box plot of the Baltimorecity Salaries open data:

[image]

```
> par(mar=c(16,4,1,1)) 
> boxplot(mydata$GROSSPAY ~ mydata$AGENCY, las=2)
```

[image]

I would like to display the boxes in order of of the total GROSSPAY of the AGENCY.

Is this possible with R?  If so, how?

---

As this question was closed, I'm pasting an answer here:

```
mydata <- mydata[ ! is.na(mydata$GROSSPAY),  ]
mydata$AGENCY <- with(mydata, reorder(AGENCY, GROSSPAY, sum))

par(las=2)
par(mar=c(16,4,1,1))
boxplot(mydata$GROSSPAY ~ mydata$AGENCY)
```

Comment: Yes. Is there anything you've already tried yourself?

Comment: No.  I have a complete mental block how to move forward on this.

Comment: If you break it down, you have two things to do. First, calculate the GROSSPAY per AGENCY, and then order the boxplots by that total. For the first one, you could use aggregate, plyr or dplyr, whatever you're comfortable with. And for the second part two links were supplied.

Comment: @Heroka - thanks, that helped a lot.  I've updated the question with the answer.

Comment: Well done! Glad I could help you go past your mental block.